# how to simplify the given integrals?

Tags: calculus

If $\frac{\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^3)^{49}dx}{\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^3)^{50}dx}$ =$\frac{m}{n}$ where m and n are relatively prime then find 2m-n.
I thought that i could use by parts to solve denominator in form of numerator but i was stuck since a term x^3 is causing trouble.Are there any other methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put
$$I=\int_0^1(1-x^3)^{49}dx$$
$$J=\int_0^1(1-x^3)^{50}dx$$
$$--------------$$
$$J=\int_0^1(1-x^3)^{50}dx=\int_0^1(1-x^3)(1-x^3)^{49}dx$$

$$=\int_0^1(1-x^3)^{49}dx-\int_0^1x^3(1-x^3)^{49}dx$$

$$=I+K$$
$$K=\int_0^1\frac{x}{3}(-3x^2)(1-x^3)^{49}dx$$
$$=\Bigl[\frac{x}{3}\frac{(1-x^3)^{50}}{50}\Bigr]_0^1-\frac{1}{150}J$$
thus

$$J=I-\frac{1}{150}J$$
or
$$\frac{151}{150}=\frac{I}{J}=\frac mn$$
then
$$2m-n=152$$